# List all commits since last release when the tag points to a commit on other branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-log, git-tag, pygit2

I need to list all the commits made to the `master` branch since my last release. I have to implement this functionality using `pygit2`. But the situation is a bit different here.

The release is made on the `master` branch using a `tag` on a commit to `other` branch. The naive approach would be to find the `sha` of the last `tagged commit` and move down the history from the `HEAD` till this `sha`. But this `tagged commit` is not made to the `master` branch in my case, it is made to `other` branch. Interestingly, the following gives the correct output when run over `master` branch:

```
$ git log sometag..HEAD --oneline
```

Here, `sometag` points to the commit made on the `other` branch. So, I want to know how could I implement this programmatically, if I have a list of all the commits made on the `master` branch.

One solution that is coming into my mind is to find the `timestamp` of the `tagged commit` and filter my commit list. How does `git log` is doing this, any ideas?

Comment: Tags aren't attached to branches, they're attached to individual commits.  A diagram would help here.  Are you trying to list commits that are ancestors of your current branch that aren't ancestors of a certain tag?

Comment: @DietrichEpp , yeah I know that. I guess you are suggesting `predecessors` of a given tag rather than `anscestors` ?

Comment: @DietrichEpp, Okay, I realised the tittle. Fixed it.

Comment: could you share the code you have done so far?

Comment: @ankcodes: I'm not sure what you mean by "predecessors" versus "ancestors".  Again, a diagram would help a lot.

Comment: I guess you can find merge base between two points (git-merge-base) and analyze paths from this base to both points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will help you: first, we use [`Repository.walk()`](http://www.pygit2.org/log.html#pygit2.Repository.walk) to get a `Walker` (commit iterator), and then we modify it ([`Walker.hide()`](http://www.pygit2.org/log.html#pygit2.Walker.hide)) to exclude all commits reachable from `sometag`:

```python
from pygit2 import Repository
from pygit2 import GIT_SORT_TIME

repo = Repository('.git')
start = repo.revparse_single('refs/heads/master')
release_tag = repo.revparse_single('refs/tags/sometag')

walker = repo.walk(start.id, GIT_SORT_TIME)
walker.hide(release_tag.id)
for commit in walker:
    print commit.message
```

Comment: thanks for this. @Roman Just a question, `walker.hide` accepting a tag object id rather than a commit id ?

Comment: another thing how does this walker work ? The commit pointed out by tag is not on the `master` branch and the walker is working on the master branch ?

Comment: @ankcodes I don't understand your first question. How does this walker work - I don't know, I only know what's written in the documentation. To the last question the answer is "yes", but again, I don't fully understand the question. Do you have an actual problem with this code?

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to know; the walker walks over the master branch till it found a tagged object but this tag is present on the other branch. Now how could it relate to(`hide`) the commit pointed by this tag which is also on other branch.

Comment: @ankcodes The walker doesn't just stop when it directly reaches the commit tagged `sometag`, it stops when it finds any commit _reachable_ (by child -> parent references) from `sometag`. At least that's how `git log sometag..master` works.